Cast MetadataService.PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility to MetadataService.ProfileRecordTypeVisibility
Is this a simple way to cast ProfileRecordTypeVisibility to PermissionSetRecordTypeVisbility using MetadataService wrapper? If not, where can i find lists of fields for each?

can we use recordTypeVisibilities instead?

I don't believe you'll be able to cast these directly as they have different fields. The ProfileRecordTypeVisibility contains two additional fields, default and personAccountDefault.
The fields for each are available in the Metadata API Developer Guide here:

ProfileRecordTypeVisibility
PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility

